# MySQL union 2 tables to order by

Tags: mysql, select, union

My ordination does not work , I want to sort table data 1

```
SELECT session_id
FROM t_table_1
WHERE dateNew BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25'
AND session_id NOT IN ((SELECT distinct session_id FROM t_table_2))
GROUP BY session_id
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 20
UNION ((SELECT DISTINCT session_id FROM t_table_2 WHERE status = '0'))
```

Order by not work

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: AND date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25'
GROUP BY session_id
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 20 not working, return error.

Comment: But what error? (escape `date` as its probably reserved btw)

Comment: exchanged , but does not work. dateNew

Comment: The SQL is completely invalid - the position of the AND clause makes no sense, should this be before the UNION?

Comment: @PaulF yes, edited my question. Order by not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT session_id
 FROM t_table_1
 WHERE dateNew BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-25'
 AND session_id NOT IN ((SELECT distinct session_id FROM t_table_2))
 GROUP BY session_id
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 20) t
UNION ALL
 ((SELECT DISTINCT session_id FROM t_table_2 WHERE status = '0'))
```